# One character change in strings in set in Python

Tags: csv, python-2.7, set

I currently have two CSV files which contain thousands values in column 1 in each csv. These values are alphanumeric uppercase characters.

My current python script populates a set for each of the CSVs to solely pick up unique values and it then compares the two sets to then just identify the entries that exist in both CSVs:-

```
import csv 
Cell1 = [x[0] for x in csv.reader(open('C:\Documents and Settings\Me\Desktop\CSV1.csv','r'))] 
Cell2 = [y[0] for y in csv.reader(open('C:\Documents and Settings\Me\Desktop\CSV2.csv','r'))] 

uniqueSet = set(Cell1) & set(Cell2) 

print uniqueSet
```

The above works no problem at all and pulls back all of the entries I expected. I'd like to develop the script one set further though and basically do a comparison between both CSVs and identify those entries which are identical except for one character. So for example, if CSV1 contains "ABCDE123" and CSV2 contains "ABCDE124", I'd like this to return a match also.

Unfortunately the length of the strings vary as I was considering running some sort of code to compare if 6 characters out of the 7 are equal for example.

Any suggestions on where to start with this one?

Comment: Do you want to keep a string _s_ in the first slice iff there exists a string _t_ in the second slice for which _s_ and _t_ have the same length and either _s_ == _t_ or just one character in one position differ?  Or can the strings have different lengths?  Do the order of characters matter?  What about 'thisstring' and 'ssihptgnit'?

Comment: It should just be one character in the same position that should be different. So both entries should be the same length but with just one value in the same position different. So for example, I wouldn't return a hit for "ABCDE123" and "ABCD124".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do asymptotically better than Theta(n^2) here.  Ultimately you are looking for:

```
result = [s from s in cell1 if matches_something_in_cell2(s)]
```

Your condition of being off by one character doesn't seem to lend itself to any kind of hashing algorithm, nor will you benefit from global sorting, which is how you do set intersection on giant sets.

You can pre-process `cell2` by partitioning it by string lengths, so when you are looking to see if a given value from `cell1` matches, you at least need only check values from `cell2` with the expected length.  This is simply pruning the search space; your algorithm will still be quadratic.

Sorting might help, but I'll leave that to you do investigate (or to another answerer who knows how it will help, or better, some ingenious data structure to solve the problem more efficiently).

In the meantime, you can try brute-forcing with a little pruning like so (pseudocode):

```
def matches_something_in_cell2(s):
    n = len(s)
    for candidate in preprocessed_list_from_cell2_of_strings_of_length(n):
        diffs = 0
        for i in range(n):
            if s[i] != candidate[i]:
                diffs += 1
                if diffs > 1
                    break
        if diffs <= 1
            return True
    return False
```

I wish I knew of a better way.  I'll delete this answer if something better comes along.